# visual studio 2017 configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am brand new to visual studio and C#. I was watching a tutorial and within vs the author clicks File -> New -> Project, and on the left under the 'installed -> Templates' tab there is a list of languages. Within each language is a list of project templates to choose from. In my vs new project window, there are no project templates. How can I get project templates to be listed here? Below I have included a screen shot of my new project window and the one in the tutorial. Thanks for the help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Repairing VS2017 solved the problem I thinks

Comment: how would I repair VS2017?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37492.modify-repair-and-uninstall-visual-studio-2017-using-visual-studio-installer.aspx

Comment: I did click on the installer. I browsed through it and it looks like C# was selected, but I didn't see anything about templates. What should I specifically be looking for in the installer?

Comment: thanks Ken. The "No templates in Visual Studio 2017" post you linked to was just what I needed.